# MySQLi database connection

Tags: php, class, mysqli

I have this (from someone else derived from my first attempt at a database class):

```
    require_once( "declarations.php" ); 

    class Database{            
        private static $mysqli;   
        private static $dbName = '';
        private static $username = '';
        private static $password = '';   
        private static $host = 'localhost';
        private static $prefix = '';   

        public function __construct(){  
            if( self::$host & self::$username & self::$password & self::$dbName )
            {
                self::$mysqli = new mysqli( self::$host, self::$username, self::$password, self::$dbName );

                 if (self::$mysqli->connect_error) {
                die('Connect Error (' . self::$mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                    . self::$mysqli->connect_error);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "You forgot to fill in your database connection details";
            }
        }

        public function Query( $query ){
            $query = self::$mysqli->real_escape_string( $query );

            if ($query = self::$mysqli->prepare($query)) {
                $query->execute();
                $query->store_result();            


                $stmt = $query->result;        
                //$query->mysql_num_rows = $stmt->num_rows();                 
                $query->close();
                return $stmt;                   
            }
        }  

        public function Close()
        {
            self::$mysqli->close(); 
        }
    }
```

This is how i'm calling it:

```
    include_once( "system/database.php" );

    $query = "SELECT * FROM app";     
    $dbr = new Database();  

    //Change this here since your method is query and not $mysqli
    while( $row = $dbr->Query( $query )->fetch_object() ){
       echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>' ;
       echo '<td>'. $row['title'] . '</td>' ;   
    }  

    Database::Close();
```

I am getting an error Call to a member function `fetch_object()` on a non-object in on the while loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: most likely your query has failed, you assumed it succeeded, and now it's blown up in your face. NEVER chain db calls. **ALWAYS** check for errors at each stage. Most likely it's because you closed the DB connection, and there is no `->result` in mysqli statement handles.

Comment: Look at your `Query()` function. It doesn't return any result if the `if` statement inside is not true. So you can't call the method `fetch_object()` on an undefined variable/object.

Answer (score -1):

fetch_object works with result set returned after query is executed with methods like: mysql_query or use fetch_assoc instead with

```
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Your logic
}
```

Comment: so what is the $query to be before using execute?

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "world"); $query = $mysqli->stmt_init(); $query->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename"); $query->execute();

Answer (score -1):

Well, your first attempt resulted with totally unusable code.
There are 2 critical faults and one serious one.

1. As I told you already, doing `$query = self::$mysqli->real_escape_string( $query );` is useless and harmful at once. You have to get rid of this line. Completely and forever.
2. Preparing a query without binding variables is totally useless.
3. You have to check for mysql errors.

So, at the very least your query() function have to be

```
public function query($query)
{
    $res = self::$mysqli->query($query);
    if (!$res)
    {
        throw new Exception(self::$mysqli->error);
    }
    return $res;
}
```

But again - this function **is not safe** as it's not not implementing placeholders to substitute data in the query.